# Docker python websocket errror : SError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] C Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 37379), [Errno 99]

Tags: python, docker, websocket

Running a python script (called localserver.py) on Raspberry Pi works perfectly, however running the same code in a docker container results in next issue:

```
smartmeter_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_eve
smartmeter_1  |     yield from self.sock_connect(sock, addr
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector
smartmeter_1  |     return (yield from fut)
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.
smartmeter_1  |     yield self  # This tells Task to wait f
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py
smartmeter_1  |     future.result()
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.
smartmeter_1  |     raise self._exception
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector
smartmeter_1  |     raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed
smartmeter_1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect
smartmeter_1  |
smartmeter_1  | During handling of the above exception, ano
smartmeter_1  |
smartmeter_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
smartmeter_1  |   File "localserver.py", line 223, in <modu
smartmeter_1  |     asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_comp
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_eve
smartmeter_1  |     return future.result()
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.
smartmeter_1  |     raise self._exception
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py
smartmeter_1  |     result = coro.throw(exc)
smartmeter_1  |   File "localserver.py", line 50, in procRe
smartmeter_1  |     'ws://localhost:37379') as websocket:
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packa
smartmeter_1  |     return await self
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packa
smartmeter_1  |     transport, protocol = await self._creat
smartmeter_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_eve
smartmeter_1  |     ', '.join(str(exc) for exc in exception
smartmeter_1  | OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] C Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 37379), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Maybe some config missing? I'm pretty new to docker, have checked some examples and existing code. Not completely sure if the port config is done correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
localserver.py -------->
async def procReadings():
    #await asyncio.sleep(30)
    async with websockets.connect(
        'ws://localhost:37379') as websocket:
.....
.....

while True:
    print(secondsDelay)
    #time.sleep(secondsDelay)
    time.sleep(5)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(procReadings())


docker-compose.yml ------------------------> 
version: '3.3'
services:
# Smartmeter
  smartmeter:
    build: ./docker
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
      - 8501:8501
      - 8546:8546
      - 37379:37379
    command: sleep infinity
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - METERID=1
    entrypoint: /etc/demo/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/etc/demo
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem?  At a first glance you're probably misusing `localhost` in a Docker context, but it's hard to tell; a single container listening on four different ports is a little odd, as is the mention of `NODE_ENV` with Python source, and the combination of command/entrypoint/volumes you show.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  The client was trying to get data before the websocket server code was running. So have added little delay and all is running fine now.